# How to access all forms from a save_related formsets in django modelAdmin

Tags: django-admin, modeladmin

I need to access two fields from all forms in a inline formsets when save_related is called, and 
save_related gives me access only the changed forms/data.

Any other solution to my problem goes, so here it is:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='items')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, default=0)


class InvoiceItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = InvoiceItem


class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InvoiceItemInline]

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        invoice = form.instance
        invoice.total = 0
        for inlines in formsets:
            for inline_form in inlines:
                invoice.total = invoice.total + inline_form.cleaned_data['price'] * inline_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        invoice.save()
        super(InvoiceAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

I need to calculate the invoice total for each invoice item, where each item has quantity * price.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a solution, so I saved the related data and used a queryset to fetch the saved data so I can do my calculation and save again.
I guess one would call this 'a workaround' :)

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    super(InvoiceAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
    invoice = form.instance
    invoice.total = 0
    for item in Invoice.objects.get(pk=invoice.id).items.all():
        invoice.total = invoice.total + item.quantity * item.price
    invoice.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Workaround around your solution. It works for me. Just changed `inline_form.cleaned_data['price']` to `inline_form.cleaned_data.get('price')`. :)

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InvoiceItemInline]

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        invoice = form.instance
        invoice.total = 0
        for inlines in formsets:
            for inline_form in inlines:
                invoice.total = invoice.total + inline_form.cleaned_data.get('price') * inline_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
        invoice.save()
        super(InvoiceAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```